# Joist in the way of drain

Tags: bathtub, drain-waste-vent

I'm installing a replacement bathtub.  Because a truss joist (3 1/2" wide & running lengthwise in the center of the tub) is in the way of the drain and overflow, I'm left to devise a bend in the vertical overflow pipe before reaching the trap.  I'm told that regarding air pressure, the overflow pipe must be vertically straight and align directly over the trap (no turns until reaching the trap). Is this true?

I'm concerned both about code and proper venting.

Thanks,  Jay

Comment: Can you cut a notch in the truss so that you don't have to bend the pipes? And /or strengthen the truss with something at right angles to it and attaching to the adjacent joists?